# vim editing multiple lines to add text at the end of text

Tags: vim

I have a following block of text.

```
`[1,2,3,4]
`[1,2,4]
`[1,2]
```

I want to add a backtick ( ` ) at the end of each line. However when I try the following key combination `<C-v>4jI`, it does add the backtick at the end of line but there is some space introduced. How do I add it at the end of the text?

With the command `C-v4jI`, the output is like this:

```
`[1,2,3,4]`
`[1,2,4]  `
`[1,2]    `
```

What I want is like this:

```
`[1,2,3,4]`
`[1,2,4]`
`[1,2]`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the lines (eg, `V4j`) and use:

```
s/$/`/
```

If there is trailing whitespace already present, you may need:

```
s/ *$/`/
```

or similar

Answer (score 0):

The command you are asking about:

```
<C-v>4jI`
```

is actually the one you used to obtain the initial state of this question:

```
`[1,2,3,4]
`[1,2,4]
`[1,2]
```

To obtain this from the previous state:

```
`[1,2,3,4]`
`[1,2,4]  `
`[1,2]    `
```

you did the following with the cursor on the last character of the first line:

```
<C-v>4jA`
```

which is the actual command you should have mentioned in your question.

Note that you only have three lines, here, so it should have actually been:

```
<C-v>2jI`
```

for the first step, and:

```
<C-v>2jA`
```

for the second step.

Now that that is out of the way, you should be able to obtain the desired result with the following command, *executed with the cursor on the first character of the first line*:

```
<C-v>2j$A`
```

Note the `$`, which extends the visual area to the end of each concerned line. That is what allows you to insert something at the end of each line.

[image: cv]

Note also that:

```
<C-v>2jI`
<C-v>2j$A`
```

is not really an efficient method for reaching your initial goal. Using a simple substitution like:

```
:,+2s/.*/`&`
```

would have been a much better approach.

Answer (score 0):

After selecting the lines you can use:

```
:normal A`
```

Note that the range `'<,'>` will be automatically added.
See `:help :normal-range`